# Why is it faster sending data as encoded string than sending it as bytes?

Tags: numpy, ipc, zeromq, pyzmq, low-latency

I'm playing with pyzmq for inter-process transfer of 4k HDR image data and noticed that this:

```
byt = np.array2string(np.random.randn(3840,2160,3)).encode()
while True:
   socket.send(byt)
```

is much much faster than:

```
byt = np.random.randn(3840,2160,3).asbytes()
while True:
   socket.send(byt)
```

Can someone explain why? I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2):

> **Q :** <sub>*Why is it*</sub> **faster** <sub>sending ... ? Can someone explain</sub> **why** <sub>?</sub>

**A :**
+1 for having asked **WHY** -
 people who do understand WHY are those, that strive to learn to the roots of the problems, so as to truly understand the core reasons & thus can next design better systems, knowing the very **WHY** ( taking no shortcuts in mimicking emulating or copy/paste following someone else )

So, let's start :

[image] HDR is not the SDR,
 we will have *"a lot of DATA"* here to acquire - store - process - send,
[image]

---

### Inventory of facts 
 <sub>- in this order : DATA, process, `.send()`, who gets faster & WHY</sub>

**DATA :**
were defined to be 4K-HDR sized array of triple-data-values of a `numpy` provided default `dtype`, where ITU-T Recommendation BT-2100 HDR colourspace requires at least 10-bit for increased colour dynamics-ranges

The as-is code delivers `numpy.random.randn( c4K, r4K, 3 )`'s default
`dtype` of `np.float64`. Just for the sake of proper & right-sized system design, the HDR ( extending a plain 8-bit sRGB triple-byte colourspace ) shall always prefer `int{10|12|16|32|...}`-based storage, not to skew any numerical image post-processing in pipeline's later phase(s).

**process :**
Actual message-payload generating processes were defined to be
*Case-A )* `np.array2string( )` followed by an `.encode()` method
*Case-B )* a `numpy.ndarray`-native *(sic)* `.asbytes()`-method

**`.send()` :**
ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Archetype pattern (of unknown type) finally receives a process-generated message-payload, into a ( ***blocking***-form of the ) `.send()`-method

---

### Solution of WHY & tips for HOW :

The core difference is hidden in the fact, that we try to compare apples to oranges.

```
>>> len(                  np.random.randn( c4K, r4K, 3 ).tobytes() ) / 1E6
199.0656 [MB]

>>> len( np.array2string( np.random.randn( c4K, r4K, 3 ) )         ) / 1E6
0.001493 [MB] ... Q.E.D.
```

While the *(sic)* `.asbytes()`-method produces a full copy ( incl. RAM-allocation + RAM-I/O-traffic **`[SPACE]`** + **`[TIME]`**-domains' costs ), i.e. spending some extra `us` before ZeroMQ starts a `.send()`-method ZeroCopy magicks :

> ```
> print(                        np.random.randn( c4K, r4K, 3 ).tobytes.__doc__ )
> a.tobytes(order='C')
>
>    Construct Python bytes containing the raw data bytes in the array.
>
>    Constructs Python bytes showing a copy of the raw contents of
>    data memory. The bytes object is produced in C-order by default.
>    This behavior is controlled by the ``order`` parameter.
>
>    .. versionadded:: 1.9.0
> ```

the other case, the *Case-A*, first throws away *(!)*, and a lot *(!)<sub>... depending here on actual `numpy` matrix-UI-presentation configuration settings</sub>*, lot of original 4K-HDR DATA even before moving them into the `.encode()`-phase :

> ```
>  >>> print( np.array2string( np.random.randn( c4K, r4K, 3 ) ) )
>  [[[ 1.54482944 -0.23189048 -0.67866246]
>    ...
>    [ 0.13461456  1.47855833 -1.68885902]]
>  
>   [[-0.18963557 -1.1869201   1.34843493]
>    ...
>    [-0.3022641  -0.44158803  0.75750368]]
>  
>   [[-1.05737969  0.864752    0.36359686]
>    ...
>    [ 1.70240612 -0.12574642 -1.03325878]]
>  
>   ...
>  
>   [[ 0.41776933  1.73473723  0.28723299]
>    ...
>    [-0.47635911  0.15901325 -0.56407537]]
>  
>   [[-1.41571874  1.66735309  0.6259928 ]
>    ...
>    [-0.93164127  0.95708002  1.3470873 ]]
>  
>   [[ 0.16426176 -0.00317156  0.77522962]
>    ...
>    [ 0.32960196 -1.74369368 -0.34177759]]]
> ```

So, sending less-DATA means taking less time to move them.

**Tips HOW :**

1. ZeroMQ methods & the overall performance will benefit from using `zmq.DONTWAIT` flag, when passing a reference to the `.send()`-method
2. try to re-use the most of the great `numpy`-tooling, where possible, to minimise repetitive RAM-allocation(s) ( we may pre-allocate & re-use once allocated variable )
3. try to use as compact DATA-representation as possible, if hunting for maximum performance with minimum latency - redundancy-avoided, compact, CPU-cache-lines' hierarchy & associativity matching formats will always win in the race for ultimate performance ( using a view of internal `numpy`-storage area, i.e. without using any mediating methods to read-access the actual block of 4K-HDR data may help to move the whole pipeline to become ZeroCopy down to the ZeroMQ `.send()`-pushing the DATA-references only ( i.e. without copying or moving a single byte of DATA from / into RAM, up until loading it onto the wire ... ) ... which is the coolest performance result of our design efforts here, isn't it? )
4. in any case, in all critical sections, avoid effects of blocking the flow by `gc.disable()`, to at least defer a potential `.collect()` not to happen "here"